# Custom num lock keypad layout

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb, numlock, numpad

I, like many people, keep the num lock key enabled all the time. However, I would like to create a custom XKB keyboard layout that maps the keypad with num lock off to what would normally be the keypad with num lock on, and when num lock is on, I want it to have a custom layout (more specifically, I want the `KP_Decimal`, `KP_Enter`, `KP_Add`, `KP_Subtract`, `KP_Multiply`, and `KP_Divide` keys to map to `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` respectively (both uppercase and lowercase, depending on shift or caps lock), in other words, I would like the num lock key to function more like a "hex lock"). First I tried to write a script that would run `xmodmap` to map the keys depending on the num lock state, but I ended up abandoning that idea when I found out that it was very slow, and that I couldn't make the script run automatically upon pressing the num lock key (because it is a strange key that makes the window lose focus when pressed). This is what I currently have (the beginning part is copied from the US keyboard layout file):

```
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    name[Group1]= "English (US) (Hex Lock)";

    modifier_map Mod2 { Num_Lock };

    key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
    key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
    key <AE03> {    [     3,    numbersign  ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [     4,    dollar      ]   };
    key <AE05> {    [     5,    percent     ]   };
    key <AE06> {    [     6,    asciicircum ]   };
    key <AE07> {    [     7,    ampersand   ]   };
    key <AE08> {    [     8,    asterisk    ]   };
    key <AE09> {    [     9,    parenleft   ]   };
    key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenright  ]   };
    key <AE11> {    [     minus,    underscore  ]   };
    key <AE12> {    [     equal,    plus        ]   };

    key <AD01> {    [     q,    Q       ]   };
    key <AD02> {    [     w,    W       ]   };
    key <AD03> {    [     e,    E       ]   };
    key <AD04> {    [     r,    R       ]   };
    key <AD05> {    [     t,    T       ]   };
    key <AD06> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
    key <AD07> {    [     u,    U       ]   };
    key <AD08> {    [     i,    I       ]   };
    key <AD09> {    [     o,    O       ]   };
    key <AD10> {    [     p,    P       ]   };
    key <AD11> {    [ bracketleft,  braceleft   ]   };
    key <AD12> {    [ bracketright, braceright  ]   };

    key <AC01> {    [     a,    A       ]   };
    key <AC02> {    [     s,    S       ]   };
    key <AC03> {    [     d,    D       ]   };
    key <AC04> {    [     f,    F       ]   };
    key <AC05> {    [     g,    G       ]   };
    key <AC06> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [     j,    J       ]   };
    key <AC08> {    [     k,    K       ]   };
    key <AC09> {    [     l,    L       ]   };
    key <AC10> {    [ semicolon,    colon       ]   };
    key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   quotedbl    ]   };

    key <AB01> {    [     z,    Z       ]   };
    key <AB02> {    [     x,    X       ]   };
    key <AB03> {    [     c,    C       ]   };
    key <AB04> {    [     v,    V       ]   };
    key <AB05> {    [     b,    B       ]   };
    key <AB06> {    [     n,    N       ]   };
    key <AB07> {    [     m,    M       ]   };
    key <AB08> {    [     comma,    less        ]   };
    key <AB09> {    [    period,    greater     ]   };
    key <AB10> {    [     slash,    question    ]   };

    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,         bar    ]   };

    key <KP0>   {   [ KP_0,     KP_0,       KP_0,       KP_0        ]   };
    key <KP1>   {   [ KP_1,     KP_1,       KP_1,       KP_1        ]   };
    key <KP2>   {   [ KP_2,     KP_2,       KP_2,       KP_2        ]   };
    key <KP3>   {   [ KP_3,     KP_3,       KP_3,       KP_3        ]   };
    key <KP4>   {   [ KP_4,     KP_4,       KP_4,       KP_4        ]   };
    key <KP5>   {   [ KP_5,     KP_5,       KP_5,       KP_5        ]   };
    key <KP6>   {   [ KP_6,     KP_6,       KP_6,       KP_6        ]   };
    key <KP7>   {   [ KP_7,     KP_7,       KP_7,       KP_7        ]   };
    key <KP8>   {   [ KP_8,     KP_8,       KP_8,       KP_8        ]   };
    key <KP9>   {   [ KP_9,     KP_9,       KP_9,       KP_9        ]   };
    key <KPDL>  {   [ KP_Decimal,   KP_Decimal, a,      A       ]   };
    key <KPEN>  {   [ KP_Enter, KP_Enter,   b,      B       ]   };
    key <KPAD>  {   [ KP_Add,   KP_Add,     c,      C       ]   };
    key <KPSU>  {   [ KP_Subtract,  KP_Subtract,    d,      D       ]   };
    key <KPMU>  {   [ KP_Multiply,  KP_Multiply,    e,      E       ]   };
    key <KPDV>  {   [ KP_Divide,    KP_Divide,  f,      F       ]   };
};
```

I have also tried the `Mod1` modifier key (which ended up inserting hex characters when shift was pressed) and some others. I have no idea what to do now.

By the way, the code above is in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbol/hex` and I select it using `setxkbmap hex`.